# I lose resolution when displaying an image in a coordinated system

Tags: matplotlib, image-processing, google-colaboratory, ipython

I have used various libraries to processs images:

IPython.display:

```
from IPython.display import Image as Im
Im(path, width = 400, height = 400)
```

cv2:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
imcv2 = cv2.imread(path)
imcv2 = cv2.resize(imcv2,(400,400))
cv2_imshow(imcv2)
```

PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
imPIL = Image.open(path)
imPIL.thumbnail((400, 400))
display(imPIL)
```

skimage.io:

```
imio = io.imread(path)
io.imshow(imio)
plt.axis('off')
io.show()
```

IPython.display resizes the figure displayed, not the image itself, while the other libraries do, so all of the images displayed seem blurred, with the exception of IPython. Here to show the difference in resolution:

IPython:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owytA.png)

Others:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv06T.png)

This is the image used:
[Image used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ8Fm.jpg)

I need to display the image in a coordinated system, but when I show the image with matplotlib it works on every single library EXCEPT with IPython.display. In the other libraries it plots in a coordinated system but with the blurry image.

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Im(path, width = 400, height = 400))
plt.title('title')
plt.show()
```

This is the code I use, I just change Im(path, width = 400, height = 400) for imPIL, imio or imcv2 depending on the library I want to plot.

The error I get with IPython.display:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-cf682188fd5a> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 plt.figure()
----> 2 plt.imshow(Im(path, width = 400, height = 400))
      3 plt.title('title')
      4 plt.show()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    699         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
    700                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
--> 701             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
    702                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
    703 

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

It plots an empty figure.

My question is if this error can be solved so I can plot the image using IPython.display? Or if there´s a way to resize just the figure using another library so the image is plotted in high resolution it would be an equivalent solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking 1) what the error message means, or 2) why you sometimes lose resolution. Either way, please provide [mcve] so we can help you. That includes either the image causing the problems, or 2-3 lines of code that produce an image with the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: The screen captures you have are showing the image a LOT larger than 400x400.  It looks like the one from IPython is not resizing at all, so of course it would be clearer.

Comment: When I use Paint.net to resize your image to 400x400, I get mush.  You should expect no better no matter which package you resize with.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn´t know a resize changed the resolution of the image, I understand now, thanks for the clarification. Then what I wanted to do was display the image in a smaller figure but without losing resolution, if I don´t use the resize the figure displayed takes the whole page. This is a test image but I need to track distances in a coordinated system, so if I lose resolution I won´t be able to track very well.